# Multiple dynamic classes for an element in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

This works, but is verbose. How to shorten this?

`.service{:class => [route.night? ? "night" : "", route.school? ? "school" : ""] * ""}`

I would like this element to have:

- `class = "service"` if not `route.night?` and not `route.school?`
- `class = "night service"` if `route.night?` and not `route.school?`
- `class = "school service"` if not `route.night?` and `route.school?`
- `class = "school night service"` if `route.night?` and `route.school?`

**EDIT**: matt helped me shorten this by three characters:

`.service{:class => [route.night? ? "night" : "", route.school? ? "school" : ""]}`

What else can be done?

Comment: What is `route`? How does it answer the questions `school?` and `night?`?

Comment: @UriAgassi `route` is a bus route, `school?` means it's a school bus route and `night?` means it's a night route.

Comment: So it is a class with two boolean members?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest implementing a helper

```
def service_class_helper(route)
  classes = ['service']
  classes << 'night' if route.night?
  classes << 'school' if route.school?
  classes
end
```

and use it in your template accordingly

```
:class => service_class_helper(route)
```

If the use of a helper is not desired you can have something like

```
.service{:class => ['night', 'school'].select { |c| c if route.send("#{c}?") } }
```

Which does the job quite simple. But is bound to some obvious limitations.

Comment: You don’t necessarilly have to call `join` – if you pass an array for the `class` element Haml will join it for you:http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I was hoping for something shorter, not longer. :) And I don't like the idea of writing view-specific helper methods.

Comment: @matt Thank you, I removed the ` * ""` from the end and it's a bit shorter now.

Comment: well, helpers are for that reason. To extract some logic in order to keep the views clean

Comment: Ok, I agree this is a good reason to have a helper, but I'm still hoping for something more concise. :) Hope I'm not naive.

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to use a helper? It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
.service{class: {night: route.night?, school: route.school?}.map{|k,v| k if v} }
```

Or, if you can refactor your `Route` class you can define it like:

```
class Route
  def initialize(night: false, school: false)
    @route_type = Set.new
    @route_type.add('night') if night
    @route_type.add('school') if school
  end

  def route_type
    @route_type.to_a
  end

  def night?
    @route_type.include? 'night'
  end

  def school?
    @route_type.include? 'school'
  end
end
```

And now you could write

```
.service { class: route.route_type }
```